# change url of picasso loaded image using timer

Tags: android, picasso

application stop working when i add picasso in timer to change url of image every 2 min

I want to get array of image url from web and put it in image view very 2min change the image i am using picasso and it worked for on url 
but when i put in timer the application stop

```
    final String [] url = {"https://png.pngtree.com/thumb_back/fh260/back_pic/00/03/20/63561dc0bf71922.jpg",
            "https://placeit-assets.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/landing-pages/make-a-twitch-banner2/Twitch-Banner-Blue-1024x324.png",
            "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQgYdaf-JhDiFVeQjL6ZRskiF1CRADiJfgDKI3PKBfCMrnnPcHP"};

    Timer adtimer = new Timer();

    adtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int count = 0  ;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView Image_view = new ImageView( getActivity());

            count++;

            if(count >= url.length )
            count = 0;

            Picasso.get()
                    .load(String.format(url[count]))
                    .fit()
                    .into(Image_view);

        }
    } , 200 , 5000);
```

Comment: Please deliver more info and reformat your code. At least reduce your code to a minimal version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer's `run` is not UI thread that's why you're getting an error. Put Picasso inside `runOnUiThread` as below:

```
adtimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int count = 0  ;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageView Image_view = new ImageView( getActivity());

            count++;

            if(count >= url.length )
            count = 0;

            // Any view update should be made in UIThread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     Picasso.get()
                        .load(String.format(url[count]))
                        .fit()
                        .into(Image_view);
                 }
             });

        }
    } , 200 , 5000);
```